# AddClaimAsync throws 'Cannot access a disposed object'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have a simple project in asp.net core mvc and I am trying to assign claims to specified user. Everything works when i create a new user and assign a claim, but when i try to get the user by id, then assign a claim, it throws:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.'

I am not sure what I should do. Tried different things with 'using' etc but nothing seems to help. The problem is with AddClaimAsync.

```
var claim = new Claim(model.ClaimName, "True");
var user = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.UserId);

if (model.ClaimValue)
{
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
}
else
{
    await _userManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user, claim);
}

await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

As for the _applicationDbContext this is the db context passed to the service via DI.

If you have any ideas I would be very thankful if you could share.

Comment: "The problem is with AddClaimAsync." Then why don;t you show us that code? And while you're at it, maybe show a bit more of `_userManager`. It seems you are disposing a context in there when you shouldn't (or rather, trying to access one when you should use a new one).

Comment: Are you disposing _applicationDbContext anywhere in the application?

Comment: What database provider do you use?

Comment: AddClaimAsync and UserManager are just the standard classes provided by asp.net. I did not create them. I am not disposing _applicationDbContext, and I am using MSSQL Server with identity and entity framework core.

Comment: Can you show the surrounding class, how you inject the context and the user manager and also tell us how the class is registered itself (and where it is used)?

Comment: Have you registered your Db context as transient?

Answer (score 0):

This error arises due to improper method signatures. You probably have declared

```
public await void OnPost(){
....
}
```

You should return `Task<IActionResult>` like below:

`public await Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){`
`....`
`}`